# Can I receiving mails in specific folder in gmail with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to receive mails in specific folder in my gmail account. Is that possible?
I have two spring boot services, one send mails and one receive mails from my Gmail account. 
When I send message, my message go to inbox by default. Can I automatically
send messages into specific folder?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Boot. You have to check the Gmail Java API to see what capabilities it provides https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Answer (score 0):

There are two tricks here for you:

1. A gmail feature: the plus sign. If your e-mail address is `someone@gmail.com`, you'll receive the e-mails sent to the `someone+wathever_extra_after_the_plus_sign@gmail.com` too.
2. You can filter the incoming e-mails by this.

see: https://gizmodo.com/how-to-use-the-infinite-number-of-email-addresses-gmail-1609458192